# R glm() formula syntax with | and >

Tags: r, glm, lm

I saw two R glm formulas which I don't know what they mean.

Suppose we have 3 variables, `x1`, `x2`, `y`. What does it mean when the formula includes `>`, e.g., `glm((y>0) ~ x1 + x2)`? What does it mean when `|` is used, e.g., `glm(y ~ x1|x2)`?

For the second one, the explanation I found is `x1` given `x2`, but I am not sure how to interpret this when `x1` and `x2` are both column vectors rather than random variables.

Comment: Did you see the first formula w/ `lm()`, or w/ `glm()`?

Comment: Although couched in terms of R specific syntax, I wonder if this is more of a statistical understanding question (ie, more appropriate for stats.SE than here). This is especially the case for the 2nd question.

Comment: That's what I thought. In this context, `>` acts as a logical operator. Ie, it outputs `TRUE` or `FALSE` (`1` or `0`). This served to dichotomize `y`, making it the kind of response variable appropriate for logistic regression. (However, doing this is probably not a good idea-you are throwing away information.)

Answer (score 10):

`>` has its usual meaning; Is `y` greater than `0` or not? This evaluates to a logical vector with `TRUE` and `FALSE` for observations greater than 0 or not, respectively. This has the effect of being treated as a vector of `1`s and `0`s (again, respectively). I presume you left out the bit where you specified a `family = binomial` or similar to account for the `0`/`1` nature of the data?

`|` doesn't have any special meaning in the formula accepted by `glm()` (and other base R functions). It takes the same meaning as `?'|'` which is an OR operator. Hence in `x1 | x2`, we might think of this as being `or(x1, x2)`, which has the form of a standard function call. The result here is `TRUE` if `x1` *or* `x2` is `TRUE`, coercing `x1` and `x2` to logical as required. If `x1` and `x2` are both numeric, the only way `x1 | x2` will be `FALSE` is if both are exactly equal to `0`. As far as this is concerned, this is just a feature of R's formulas and *standard non-standard evaluation*; A formula can contain function calls, such as `log(x)`, `sqrt(y)` etc, which get evaluated when the fitting function collects the data needed for fitting.

Here is an example that might explain what `|` is  doing in a formula:

```
> set.seed(1)
> df <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(5), A = rnorm(5), B = rep(FALSE, 5),
+                  C = c(rep(TRUE, 4), FALSE))
> df
           Y          A     B     C
1 -0.6264538 -0.8204684 FALSE  TRUE
2  0.1836433  0.4874291 FALSE  TRUE
3 -0.8356286  0.7383247 FALSE  TRUE
4  1.5952808  0.5757814 FALSE  TRUE
5  0.3295078 -0.3053884 FALSE FALSE
> model.frame(Y ~ A + (B | C), data = df)
           Y          A B | C
1 -0.6264538 -0.8204684  TRUE
2  0.1836433  0.4874291  TRUE
3 -0.8356286  0.7383247  TRUE
4  1.5952808  0.5757814  TRUE
5  0.3295078 -0.3053884 FALSE
```

The third column here is formed from a call to `'|'(A, B)`, which results in

```
> with(df, B | C)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Notice that you have to wrap the `|` clause in parentheses otherwise it gobbles up the other terms on the right-hand side of the `~`:

```
> model.frame(Y ~ A + B | C, data = df)
           Y A + B | C
1 -0.6264538      TRUE
2  0.1836433      TRUE
3 -0.8356286      TRUE
4  1.5952808      TRUE
5  0.3295078      TRUE

## Note there is no `A` and all are `TRUE` now.
```

The reason the last element is now `TRUE`, notice that the last element of `A` (`-0.3053884`) is not exactly equal to `0` and hence it evaluates to `TRUE`, hence we have `TRUE | FALSE`, which results in `TRUE`.

`|` *does* have special meaning in other packages, for example in the **lme4** package, where it is used to nest random effects.

Comment: @jderzol, if this answer has resolved your issue, then you may consider *accepting* it by clicking on the check mark to its upper left below the vote total. You may also want to consider *upvoting* it by clicking the upwards facing triangle.